# (There's no) implicit conversion when used in numerical expression?

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion

I have some special numeric class. The class can be constructed by a double:

```
struct FancyDouble{
  FancyDouble& operator = (double v){
    this->value = v;
    return *this;
  }
};

FancyDouble myFancyDouble = 5.0;
```

**The class provides an (implicit) conversion from `double` to `FancyDouble`. Is there a way to do the opposite?** So when I use a `FancyDouble` in a numeric expression, I'd like to write:

```
double a = 123;
double b = b * myFancyDouble;
```

I had a look into the reference and I think it's not possible, but I'm not absolutely sure.

Comment: The presence of *assignment* operator you quoted above has nothing to do with the fact that the class can be *initialized* with a `double` during construction. The latter is supported by class constructors. It does not involve assignment operator in any way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can. They are called conversion operators:

```
struct FancyDouble
{
    // your things here
    operator double() { return this->value; }
};
```

You can have a conversion to any type, not just built-in types. They are also typically marked `const` (though I didn't do it here to show the core concept).

Note that your struct (as shown) doesn't exactly allow implicit conversions from `double` to `FancyDouble`; your `operator=` only means that you can use a double on the right-hand side of an assignment, but if you have a `FancyDouble` function parameter, it won't work since what you would need there is a constructor that accepts a double, not an assignment operator.

```
void foo(FancyDouble fd);
foo(4.4); // does not work because you can't construct a FancyDouble from a double
          // even though you have an assignment operator
```

You would do something like this:

```
struct FancyDouble
{
    // your things here
    FancyDouble(double d) { /* initialization here */ }
};
```

With this, you would only need an `operator=` that accepts a `FancyDouble` instead of a `double`, and the conversion would be done automatically:

```
struct FancyDouble
{
    // your things here
    FancyDouble(double d) { /* initialization here */ }
    FancyDouble& operator=(FancyDouble fd) { /* assignment here */ }
};

FancyDouble fd = 4.2; // works
fd = 5.5; // also works, because FancyDouble can be constructed implicitly from a double
```

Comment: Please do not use an implicit constructor (taking a double) and an implicit conversion operator (to double) in one class.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this great answer!